# create objects on form submit in typescript angular 7

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, angular7

I am trying to create 2 separate objects on form submission. Below is my code:

**test.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="gamificationForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

<div *ngFor="let medal of medalResponse; let iMedal=index" class="row col-lg-12 mtop-custom-10 medal-level-point-config">
      <input type="hidden" class="point-text" [(ngModel)]="medal.medalId" formControlName="medalId" />
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
        {{medal.medalName}}
        <input type="hidden" class="point-text" [(ngModel)]="medal.medalName" formControlName="medalName" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-6">
        <input type="number" class="point-text" [(ngModel)]="medal.points" formControlName="points" />
      </div>
    </div>

<button class="custom-btn-class" name="submit" type="submit">Save</button>

</form>
```

**Typescript:**

```
    gamificationForm = this.fb.group({
    medals: this.fb.group({
      medalId: [''],
      medalName: [''],
      points: ['']
    })
  });

onSubmit() {
    console.warn(this.gamificationForm.value);
}
```

**JSON:**

```
It is printing last values from the loop on html page and in json too.
```

Comment: what is your expectation?

Comment: Have you looked into reactive forms?

Comment: as @r2018said, if you want form automatically gives you well-formatted object, you should use reactive forms, exactly - nested formsGroup. Take a look at it here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-nested-group

Comment: Sure. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Serhiy I tried but I am not sure how to deal with dynamic values. It renders only last values in ts file on click of button. Can you please guide?

Comment: @PathikVejani Sure, can you, please, set up the form, how it's now on https://stackblitz.com/ ? 
In case you never use it - it's like codepen, only more comfortable for use with Angular in my opinion. You need to scroll a little bit down and press start a new workspace with Angular.

Comment: @Serhiy thanks for your time, I managed.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert this JSON value to your required format,

```
format(value) {
  return [
     {
       Level: [
         {
          "levelId-0":value.levelId-0,
          "level-0":value.level-0,
          "points-0":value.points-0
         },
         ....
       ],
       Medal: [
         .....
       ]
     }
  ]
}
```

Comment: How do I convert it? Any explanations for your answer?

Comment: All data is coming dynamically, how can we make object for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't done this via [Template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms) Forms, but here my ideas:

You will need to group your fields into the `Level` and `Medal` arrays by wrapping your `*ngFor` into a `<ng-container formArrayName="Level">` container and try it.

Each `*ngFor` should set the position `FormArray`, but you will need to experiment and see if the `formArrayName` directive does it for you.

Happy ng-coding!

Comment: I don't have any idea for that. Can you provide some example?